# Redirect Match with excluding URLs doesnt work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I use a `RedirectMatch` rule which should exclude the following two URLs:

- `citycards/citycards-locations/munche‌​n/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachst‌​r-47-munchen`
- `citycards/citycards-location‌​s/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen`

I use this rule with regex, but I get a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munche‌​n/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachst‌​r-47-munchen|citycards/citycards-location‌​s/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen ).+)$ /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: What language are you using?  If you just need to exclude these two URLs, could you do it manually in your app layer?

Comment: we use german... no, we have to exclude more urls with other redirect match rules....

Comment: Funny, I was asking about your _programming_ language.

Comment: php ;-).............

Comment: What do you see in error logs?

Comment: Could you provide example of what it should match ?

Comment: Maybe first thoroughly test your regex in a place like (Regex101)[www.regex101.com] and then deal with the PHP issue separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule currently is: (broken down to multiple lines for better display/understanding):

```
RedirectMatch
301
/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munche‌​n/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachst‌​r-47-munchen|citycards/citycards-location‌​s/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen ).+)$
/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1
```

Basically, your regex says that:

- match `/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/`
- which is not followed by either of the following

  1. `citycards/citycards-locations/munche‌​n/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachst‌​r-47-munchen`,
  2. `citycards/citycards-location‌​s/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen` (it has a space after `18‌​-munchen`)
- match everything until the end of URI

and redirect the matched URI to: `/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/$1` which is basically the same URL that was matched against.

I see 2 issues.

1. If the blank space in your negative lookahead is not considered as a part of the pattern, you are essentially passing 4 arguments to `RedirectMatch` directive, leading to status 500 error
2. If the pattern is getting parsed correctly, you have an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: ah... i will check this tomorrow, but  you are right the blank space isnt right...but the redirectmatch works without the excluding urls fine... 

**RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/ http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen$1**

urls from this type: **/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/blabla** are redirected to **/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen**

Comment: ok, after i removed the blank space there is no 500 Internal Server Error ! But the regex also dont works...

Comment: **RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/ http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen$1** this works fine but with Regex (ecluding urls) it doesnt work: **RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-trachtenvogl-reichenbachstr-47-munchen|citycards/citycards-locations/munchen/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18-munchen).*)$ http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/munchen$1** Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> `/citycards-4-you-munchen-hirtenstrasse-18‌​-munchen ).+)$`

You have an unescaped space near the end of your `RewriteRule` pattern. This will certainly cause a 500 error since the space is a delimiter and the arguments will not match up (invalid flags).

It looks like this is a typo and should simply be removed?